# What is the word for transliteration into the Greek alphabet?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific term for transliteration of a different script **into the Greek alphabet**? There are equivalent terms for transliteration of other alphabets into the Latin alphabet (romanization) and the Cyrillic alphabet (cyrillization). However, I can find no counterpart for transliteration into Greek. My closest guess would be *hellenization*, but that term is already used in historical contexts, referring to conversion of other nations to Greek culture (rather than transliteration into the Greek alphabet). I would like to know the term for this, as I am trying to find a transliteration scheme for converting English into the modern Greek alphabet, but searching for *Greek transliteration* only yields information on Greek romanization (which is the inverse of what I want). Any word or phrase will do, so long as it unambiguously refers to transliterating a script into the Greek alphabet, and not to romanization of Greek.

Comment: Since Greek doesn't have a 1-1 mapping into English letters you never can get a totally unambiguous result, that is one that could be reversed perfectly.

Comment: That doesn't mean such a process is not productive. Many non-Greek words _are_ transliterated into Greek for everyday use from several languages, usually from the Latin alphabet. This includes, but is not limited to, proper names of course, such as Λονδίνο (London). I am not sure there is a word for it, I will ask my wife :)

Comment: Λονδίνο is not a transliteration of *London*, but a translation, just as the English *Moscow* is not a transliteration of *Mockba*.

Comment: I didn't say it was unproductive, just not unambiguous. I did it a lot in high school, and we just had conventions for letters like W or C (hard vs soft) and so on.

Comment: You could call it _Hellenification_, which mixes Greek and Latin roots, or _Greekification_, which mixes English and Latin roots. Your choice. There's probly some Greek causative form that would do the same job as Latin _-ficere_ suffix (from _facere_ 'make, do, cause'), but nobody would recognize it, so it wouldn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Grecization** is sometimes used in this sense, though it is used for transliteration into Greeklish (or romanized Greek), translation into Greek and used in the sense of Hellenization as well.

> **[grecize](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grecize)**
>
> **1.** (transitive) To render Grecian, or cause (a word or phrase in another language) to take a Greek form.
>
> *The name is grecized.*
>
> **2.** (transitive) To translate into Greek.
>
> **3.** (intransitive) To conform to the Greek custom, especially in speech.

On the other hand, hellenization is used for the transliteration into Greek also. As in [hellenized transliteration](https://www.google.ca/#q=%22hellenized+transliteration%22&safe=off).

Apparently, there is no well-established term for transliteration into Greek (or Greek alphabet).

Answer (score 0):

Consider [**grecianize**](http://www.whyapostolic.com/html/jesus.html) and "**[grecianizatiom](http://www.yourdictionary.com/grecianize)**."

> **grecianize**: to make Greek; give a a Greek form to; hellenize.